# Unknown type name 'Facebook'

Tags: facebook, xcode4, ios5

I just tried incorporating the FB SDK into my app as described online.

I made it to the point where they say to test the app but I had 23 errors, most of which were parse issues that said unknown type name 'Facebook'.

[This image](http://erresapp.com/files/fb1.png) shows the sdk as installed in my project.

[This image](http://erresapp.com/files/fb2.png) shows some of the errors.

Any ideas??

Josh

Comment: Do you have `#import "Facebook/Facebook.h"` in your erres_appDelegate.h?  From the look of your source file syntax highlighting it looks like Xcode can't resolve the object

Comment: Any luck with this? I can;t get it to  work either.